# Overclocking In Linux With Wolf or Silentarmy

Tags: gpu-mining, linux, mining-software

Does anyone know of an overclocking utility for AMD/ATI cards in Linux similar to wattman for windows? The latest crimson drivers don't seem to have such a utility built in. Moreover, the settings for overclocking in wolf's xmr miner don't seem to do anything and I don't see similar settings in silentarmy's miner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried on Lubuntu 16.04 with [sgminer-gm](https://github.com/genesismining/sgminer-gm), and the settings didn't seem to change anything as well. It is as if the card is just ignoring the OC settings.

It seems that for Linux, it's not so straight-forward to OC. I remember reading somewhere that you can do it by changing the GPU BIOS. Haven't done it myself yet so can't really give guidelines.

[Here](http://nerdralph.blogspot.hr/2016/09/monero-mining-on-linux.html) I found mention use of some aticonfig script to OC. Maybe it's worth investigating further. Some more info [here](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/8250/ubuntu-16-04-lts-rx-480-mining-ethereum-confirmed-working).